# R Wildcard data frame merging

Tags: regex, r, merge, dataframe

I'm trying to merge a data frame and vector not by exact string matches in a column, but by wildcard string matches. To clarify, say you have this dataframe:

```
v <-data.frame(X1=c("AGTACAGT","AGTGAAGT","TGTA","GTTA","GAT","GAT"),X2=c(1,1,1,1,1,1))
#         X1 X2
# 1 AGTACAGT  1
# 2 AGTGAAGT  2
# 3     TGTA  3
# 4     GTTA  4
# 5      GAT  5
# 6      GAT  6
```

I want to create a dataframe by creating a different color for every `AGT.{3}GT`,`.{T|G}TA`,`GAT` pattern, and creating a new column `X3` that would show that color. So something like this:

```
#         X1 X2        X3
# 1 AGTACAGT  1 "#FE7F01"
# 2 AGTGAAGT  2 "#FE7F01"
# 3     TGTA  3 "#FE7F00"
# 4     GTTA  4 "#FE7F00"
# 5      GAT  5 "#FE8002"
# 6      GAT  6 "#FE8002"
```

So far I am using this to create colors for each level, but I don't know how to count how many "wildcard levels" as opposed to singular levels there are:

```
x <- nlevels(v$X1)
x.colors2 <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8,"Paired"))(x)
G <- data.frame("X1"=levels(v$X1),"X3"=x.colors2)
v <- merge(v,G)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution.

Find patterns:

```
pat <- c("^AGT.{3}GT$", "^.(T|G)TA$", "^GAT$")
n <- length(pat)
indList <- lapply(pat, grep, v$X1)
```

Generate colors:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
col <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8, "Paired"))(n)
```

Add colors to data frame:

```
colFull <- rep(col, sapply(indList, length))
v$color <- colFull[order(unlist(indList))]
```

The result:

```
v
#         X1 X2   color
# 1 AGTACAGT  1 #A6CEE3
# 2 AGTGAAGT  1 #A6CEE3
# 3     TGTA  1 #979C62
# 4     GTTA  1 #979C62
# 5      GAT  1 #FF7F00
# 6      GAT  1 #FF7F00
```